# UITextField .text attribute always returns an empty string

Tags: ios, objective-c, string, uitextfield, editing

I'm programming forms for my iOS app, and my `UITextField`s act strangely :

When the form is in update state (fields are already filled) I can edit and get the new input text (typed by user) with the `.text` attribute. But when the form is in insert mode the `UITextField`s are initially empty and I cannot get the text typed then by the user with the `.text` attribute because it always returns an empty string whatever the user types.
Here is a video showing the issue : https://youtu.be/tPJZ3sC-IFU

```
{
    __weak IBOutlet UITextField *txtLibelle; //linked by ctrl + drag to the storyboard
    NSString *libelleTemp;
}
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

    // ...

    [txtLibelle addTarget:self
                   action:@selector(editingChanged:)
         forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];

    // ...

}

-(void) editingChanged:(id)sender {
    libelleTemp = txtLibelle.text;
    // libelleTemp is set to @"" whatever the user has typed in when I'm in insert mode
}

-(void)initWithLib:(NSString *)lib {
    libelleTemp = [NSString stringWithString:lib];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [super tableView:tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    if (indexPath.section == 0) {
        txtLibelle.text = libelleTemp;
    }

    // ...

    return cell;
}
```

The initWithLib: method is called from the previous view controller like this :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UIStoryboard *accueilNavSB = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    FicheAlerteTableViewController *vc = [accueilNavSB instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"ficheAlerte"];
    NSString *libelle = @"";
    [vc initWithLib:libelle];
    [self.navigationController showViewController:vc sender:self];
}
```

I already have relinked the field from the storyboard to my class, and in debug mode my `UITextField` is not nil.

My textfields are in a static `UITableView`, so I can see if the update worked scrolling the cell off the screen then scrolling it on.

Does anyone know why is this happening and how to solve the problem?

Comment: what do you mean you cannot get the input text by .text?

Comment: If the text fields are empty in the insert mode,how can you get the string by .text attribute? Anyway it is an empty string.

Comment: The code you mentioned, is gonna work only once,because you are calling that method in view did load

Comment: However when I set a breakpoint in the editingChanged: method I can see that it is called for each character I'm typing in the textfield. And yet txtLibelle.text is still an empty string...

Comment: yes,it is because you are not setting the text properly.

Comment: I didn't noticed but I havent say in the code that libelleTemp is a NSString * attribute of my class. I edit my question...

Comment: any way u need to use text attribute for ur string !!!

Comment: There's no text attribute for NSString objects...

Comment: Ok,let me edit my answer...i hhtought...it is a uilabel

Comment: If you're using a static table view, you shouldn't be implementing any of the data source methods, like cellForRowAtIndexPath.

Comment: I know but I had to handle some light changes on other cells. However I'm using UITextViews on other cells and they react perfectly. My problem is confined to UITextFields.

Comment: rdelmar you're right. I will change this, I think I have no choice. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

There is one error in your code. You are not using the correct attribute to load the text into the label.Use This.

This worked for me. I tested this on my Xcode.

```
-(void) editingChanged:(id)sender {
  //label1.text = field.text;
   libelleTemp=field.text;
    NSLog(@"text is %@",libelleTemp);
   // libelleTemp is set to @"" whatever the user has typed in when I'm in insert mode
}
```

Comment: That's not working, I think the problem is somewhere else. It acts just like the user hasn't typed anything. field.text still returns an empty string.

Comment: I tested the on my Xcode and it worked fine. Could you please show the code how you are declaring the string and how you are accessing it?>

Comment: I'm putting this to the question (I already added a video showing the problem).

Comment: where are you calling the initWithLib?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a UITextField, which can use the UITextFieldDelegate to register editing events and such. See Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/) for more information.

I believe the method you are looking for is:

```
<UITextFieldDelegate> //link your textField.delegate = self

- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
    libelleTemp = textField.text;
}
```

Another thing you could try is directly linking an (IBAction) method instead of setting the target programatically. Just control drag to link this method to your text field in IB.

```
- (IBAction)libelleEndedEditing:(UITextField *)sender {
    libelleTemp = sender.text;
}
```

Comment: I already tried this, but not solving my problem. The .text attribute is still empty. I think the problem is not related to the handling of the events.

Comment: Well I'm not sure, but look into the way you instantiate this view controller. Best practice would be to perform a segue and access it from there. And call initwithlib in viewdidload

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong action. UITextField's 'text' property will only be set once the editing has ended. So you need to wire your method to the "Editing Ended" event in Interface Builder.